# QGIS stopEditing function in python

Tags: python, pyqgis, editing, function, syntax

I am trying to stop the edits using the python console of the QGIS and the code `QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools.stopEditing(layer,False)` where layer is the layer in the edit mode.

I am receiving the following error:
`NameError: name QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools is not defined`

Does anyone know the right syntax for the [QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsTrackedVectorLayerTools.html) function?

Comment: You will need to import it using `from qgis.gui import QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools` and then use `QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools().stopEditing(layer, True)`. Unfortunately, this crashes my QGIS and I'm unsure if this is the correct method to stop the editing of a layer.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph.The way you call this method seems correct, but it crashes my Qgis too.

Comment: @Joseph can confirm it crashes my 2.18.12 as well

Answer (score 4):

QgsVectorLayerTools instance is exposed by QgisInterface (iface), you can stop editing with:

```
iface.vectorLayerTools().stopEditing(layer,False)
```

*iface.vectorLayerTools() by default returns QgsGuiVectorLayerTools.
Tested with QGIS 2.18*

Comment: Good job. It also works with QGIS 3.4.

Comment: Docs: https://www.qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsVectorLayerTools.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayerTools.stopEditing

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to this QGIS documentation page [QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools Class Reference](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsTrackedVectorLayerTools.html)

[image]

It provides this sample code:

```
1 /***************************************************************************
2   qgstrackedvectorlayertools.cpp - QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools
3 
4  ---------------------
5  begin                : 16.5.2016
6  copyright            : (C) 2016 by Matthias Kuhn, OPENGIS.ch
7  email                : matthias@opengis.ch
8  ***************************************************************************
9  *                                                                           *  
10  *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify    *
11  *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
12  *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
13  *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
14  *                                                                         *
15  ***************************************************************************/
16 #include "qgstrackedvectorlayertools.h"
17 #include "qgsvectorlayer.h"
18 
19 QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools::QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools()
20     : mBackend( nullptr )
21 {
22 }
23 
24 bool QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools::addFeature( QgsVectorLayer* layer, const QgsAttributeMap& defaultValues, const QgsGeometry& defaultGeometry, QgsFeature* feature ) const
25 {
26   QgsFeature* f = feature;
27   if ( !feature )
28     f = new QgsFeature();
29 
30   if ( mBackend->addFeature( layer, defaultValues, defaultGeometry, f ) )
31   {
32     mAddedFeatures[layer].insert( f->id() );
33     if ( !feature )
34       delete f;
35     return true;
36   }
37   else
38   {
39     if ( !feature )
40       delete f;
41     return false;
42   }
43 }
44 
45 bool QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools::startEditing( QgsVectorLayer* layer ) const
46 {
47   return mBackend->startEditing( layer );
48 }
49 
50 bool QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools::stopEditing( QgsVectorLayer* layer, bool allowCancel ) const
51 {
52   return mBackend->stopEditing( layer, allowCancel );
53 }
54 
55 bool QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools::saveEdits( QgsVectorLayer* layer ) const
56 {
57   return mBackend->saveEdits( layer );
58 }
59 
60 void QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools::setVectorLayerTools( const QgsVectorLayerTools* tools )
61 {
62   mBackend = tools;
63 }
64 
65 void QgsTrackedVectorLayerTools::rollback()
66 {
67   QMapIterator<QgsVectorLayer*, QgsFeatureIds> it( mAddedFeatures );
68   while ( it.hasNext() )
69   {
70     it.next();
71     it.key()->deleteFeatures( it.value() );
72   }
73 
74   mAddedFeatures.clear();
```